# load the data from csv to dictionary

Tags: python, python3, dictionary

I am trying to load data from CSV to dictionary line by line. I'm trying to add the data without duplicates: `," imsi = line[1] & site= line[3]"`. If the imsi and site already exist in the dictionary, I just want to aggregate the values with new line without duplicates.

```
imsi = line[1] & site= line[3]
20190102,100000000204197,google.com,4799,1394,1,1
20190102,100000000204197,yahoo.com,11626,5635,5,4
20190102,100000000204197,yahoo.com,11625666,563345,5,12
20190102,41602323232,youtube.com,7875,5710,4,4
20190102,41602323232,,youtube.com,11,3
```

```python
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse
from collections import Counter
import csv
with open('/home/mahmoudod/Desktop/Tareq-Qassrawi/report.txt','r') as rf:
    reader = csv.reader(rf)
    with open ('/home/mahmoudod/Desktop/Tareq-Qassrawi/writer.txt','w') as wf:
        hashing_table = {}
        connection_val= 0
        connection_val_2=0
        for line in reader:
            key = int(line[1])
            if key != hashing_table.items():
                hashing_table =({'IMSI':key
                ,'SITE':str(line[2])
                ,'DATE':str(line[0])
                ,'linkup' :int(line[3])
                ,'linkdown':int(line[4])
                ,'count':int(line[5])
                ,'connection':int(line[6])
                    })
                connection_val = connection_val + int(hashing_table.get('connection'))
                print (connection_val)
            else:
                connection_val_2 = connection_val_2 + int(hashing_table.get('connection'))
                print (connection_val_2)
```

Comment: is there a reason why you do not want a pandas dataframe?

Comment: newbie python , so i dont know how can do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pandas you can simply achieve this by the following example. The header should be provided in the first line of the csv file. And rename the report.txt to report.csv.

```
import pandas as pd
import random

path_csv = '/home/mahmoudod/Desktop/Tareq-Qassrawi/report.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(path_csv, header=0)  
df.head()
```